# Hide saving location in saving dialog VBA

Tags: vba

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to hide this dialog box I used below code?

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Comment: Which command do you use? `SaveAs`? Insert your code too so we can have a bit more info! ;)

Comment: I am trying to save a pdf in Network drive that takes time like 30 seconds and showing the saving location. I want to hide this saving location

Comment: So... do you have any code or are you manually saving it?

Comment: I am trying to save it by code. in code i used -   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False   But Still seen this mesage